# Binding domain and SMTP server on a foreign server

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, smtp, plesk

I have a trouble with my server setup, I'm trying to bind both IP domain + his  SMTP server on the same external server.
However mxtoolbox still give me the same error : "Reverse DNS is not a valid Hostname"

I uploaded some pictures, so it is easier to understand my problem.

1) The main domain name belongs to OVH (hosting service)

2) External server configuration:

[image: Here]

3) I added DNS settings on plesk.

4) Here the result on mxtoolbox:

[image: Here]

In this way I cannot send some email via SMTP without be considered as spam by  gmail or hotmail. I could be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You're announcing your MX record as "mail.occultant-artificiel.com", but the reverse DNS is set to "occultant-artificiel.com".  This is probably the cause of the failure on mxtoolbox.  You could consider adding an additional IP to your server, binding the SMTP server to that IP address, and setting the DNS so that the A record for "mail..." points to the new IP, and the reverse for the new IP is also "mail...".

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try this and tell you what happen.

Comment: It works thank you, but now I have this error :IP: 178.170.124.210
HELO: mail.occultant-artificiel.com
rDNS: occultant-artificiel.com. I'm trying another issue

Comment: @Alex72 at a guess, you are still making an outbound SMTP request from the IP address with occultant-artificiel.com as it's PTR.  If you have set up reverse DNS for a different IP to use the mail hostname from, try rebinding your MTA to make outbound requests using that IP address which has mail.occultant-artificiel.com as it's PTR.

Answer (score 0):

You have a valid RDNS record for the mail server IP address 178.170.124.210. The RDNS record should be FQDN which you have already set. I am not sure why the MXTOOLBOX giving it as a warning!

Comment: So, do you advise to remove RDNS record ?